# How to create a n to n matrix in python with input value diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a probabilistic calculation and I could run my code for a small matrix like;

```
P_4 = np.array([
    
     [0  ,1  ,0  ,  0,  0],
     [0  ,1/4,3/4,  0,  0],
     [0  ,0  ,2/4,2/4,  0],
     [0  ,0  ,0  ,3/4,1/4],
     [0  ,0  ,0  ,  0,1  ],
   
])
```

However, I would like to create a N*N matrix and to fill the values diagonally 0/n and next value 1 - 0/n.

```
n = 5

a = np.zeros((n,n),dtype = int)

np.fill_diagonal(a,np.array([range(1/n)]))

a
```

writing the above code gives me the error

> `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

I would a appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The error is coming from the ```range(1/n)```. range() cannot take a float. So what are you trying to get from there?

Comment: @D.Manasreh, I am trying to get the values as you can see on the top matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using [`linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and [`diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html).

```
n = 5
diag = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
diag1 = (1 - diag[:-1])
a = np.diag(diag) + np.diag(diag1, 1)
a
```

Output:

```
array([[0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.25, 0.75, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.75, 0.25],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ]])
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a simple way that I could do it.